# Simulating Cox-PH data in Python

Tags: python, random, sampling, survival-analysis, scikit-survival

Suppose I want to sample from the cox-PH model. I have some covariates and my baseline hazard function is $2t$.

Is there are an easy method to do so?

Comment: Pysurvival module, perhaps? https://square.github.io/pysurvival/models/coxph.html